# Match 2 cell and do a conditional formatting

Tags: excel, formatting, if-statement, conditional-statements

[image]Excel question:
User will input value in E3
ex: `E3 = 1`

```
// AK11 will count the values in row B11-AJ11

AK11=COUNTA(B11:AJ11)-COUNTIF(B11:AJ11,"*"&"MVR"&"*")
```

ex: `Q11="I"` and `AF11="R"`, this makes `AK11 = 2`

How do I match cell `E3` and cell `AK11`?

If they match, I have cell `AL11` that will have the conditional formatting:

```
numbers don't match = Red Pattern with White font and a string "!"  
numbers match = White Pattern with White font (basically a blank cell)
```

If I did a test on a seperate cell without AK11's COUNTA formula

AM11=1 / AN11=1 / AO11 = IF(AM11=AN11,"Y","N") | RESULTS = Y

AM11 = 1 / AN11 = 2 AO11 = IF(AM11=AN11,"Y","N") | RESULTS = N

But If I run the COUNTA formula on AN11, RESULTS always says "N".

For some reason it doesn't work with the COUNTA formula being in 1 of the matching Cell.

Comment: You say there's a question in there, but I don't see any `?`.

Comment: Put `IF(E3=AK11, ...)` into cell AL11's conditional formatting formula?

Comment: didn't work. I put the code to both the insert function bar and conditional formatting section. i deleted AF11 to make the total count of AK11 as 1 to match E3's 1. But cell AL11 still says "N"

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to understand what you're asking exactly, there's so much noise in your question. But if you're asking about the conditional formatting bit, then this is how to do it:

Just write the `!` in your cell, and give it the "default format" you want, i.e. white font and white background.

Then in conditional formatting, use Formula Is `=$AK11<>$E3` and set your red background pattern.

Here's an example with cells E3 and G3 (AK11 is too far out to the right to show).

[image]

Comment: What if you type `=E3<>AK11`? Does it say TRUE or FALSE? And what about `=E3<>AK11`?

Comment: i.e. type that in a cell somewhere